# How to get the stock price of ^NSEI

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the price of nifty index from yahoo finance.  I am using thise code:

```
import urllib
import re

url= 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^nsei'
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext =htmlfile.read()
regex ='<span id="yfs_l10_^nsei">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
price =re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print price
```

But the output is an empty list.  What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `^` in `regex`. It should be:

```
regex ='<span id="yfs_l10_\^nsei">(.+?)</span>'
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to use a raw string. So simply `r'<span id="yfs_l10_^nsei">(.+?)</span>'` is all you need

Comment: @smac89 no, that will not work. The raw string just avoids that you need to escape backslashes, it doesn't make `^` a non-special char in regexps.